# SvelteKit redirect from hook.js

Tags: hook, svelte, sveltekit

After new version of svelteKit, you have to move your script type "module" to the file hook.js

But from this hook file i cannot redirect.

Do someone know about some solution please?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding something, the scripts you put earlier in `context="module"` are most likely to be found in `+page.js` nowadays, not in `hooks.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Worked for me**

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment'
import { goto } from '$app/navigation'

export async function load({ url }) {
    if (browser) {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        // check if user token exists
        if (!token) {
            goto('/login')
        }
    }
    return url
}
```

**Didn't work:**

- import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit ... redirect('/login')
- return {status: 302, redirect: '/login'}